# Equivalence of IsA and Roles in ER diagrams?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

So clearly these two concepts aren't always considered equivalent, but would

[image: A part with roles 'engine' and 'gasket' taking part in a 'contains' relationship]

be the same thing (if more concise) as this?

[image: A part subtyped into 'motor' and 'gasket' with motor and gasket taking part in a 'contains' relationship]

Ignoring the fact that I typo'd engine to motor, if they aren't equivalent, how do the above two diagrams differ?

Edit: I was hoping on more of an elaboration on the 'contains' relationship inside the IsA diagram; is it valid? Do both of these diagrams (roughly) evaluate to the same relational schema? It would seem as though the generated tables would only differ by one column (an enumerated 'type' column), if making the bold assumption that gaskets and engines do not contain any disjoint properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first diagram illustrates the Has-a relationships.  Parts contain other parts.  An engine contains a lot of parts, some of which are gaskets.

The second diagram illustrates Is-a relationships. A part can be an engine, or it can be a gasket, or it can be a lot of other things.

In the world of abstract ER modeling, Is-a relationships go by the name of Generalization-Specialization.  I'm saying "abstract ER modeling" because a lot of ER diagrams really depict a relational model, no matter what it looks like.

It's when you switch from the ER model to a relational model that things start to get interesting.

The Has-a relationships are easy to model in relational terms.  This is practically Relational modeling 101.  You put a foreign key on the many side that references a primary key on the one side and you're done.

The Is-a relationships are not so easy to model in relational terms.  In Object modeling, this turns out to be practically Object Modeling 101.  You simply use classes and subclasses (sometimes called types and subtypes) and the inheritance feature of Object modeling does all the heavy lifting for you.

In relational modeling, things aren't so easy.  There are well known techniques for dealing with this case, but these techniques are often skipped over in tutorials on Relational modeling.  For a detail of one of these techniques, I'm going to refer you to the tag wiki under this tag:  [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance).

You would think that ORM tools would shine in this area, but it seems that they don't.

**Edit:**  One point to emphasize again:  ER modeling and table design are not the same activity.  One doesn't design the entities and relationships that make up the subject matter.  One discovers the entities and relationships by studying the subject matter, or perhaps by interviewing subject matter experts. Then one designs tables to serve as convenient containers for all the data values that describe the previously discovered entities and relationships.

In real life, this can be a reiterative process.

Now let's turn to two possible table designs to cover the second of your diagrams.

The first design is the 4-Table design.  There will be four tables:  Part, Motor, Gasket, and Motor_Gasket.  The four primary keys will be PartID, MotorID, GasketID, and (MotorID, GasketID) a compound primary key.

MotorID will not be populated via autonumber.  Instead, the application will supply a copy of the PartID just generated when an new Motor is included.  The MotorID then does double duty:  It serves as a PK in its own table, and also serves as an FK that references PartID.

GasketID gets a similar treatment.  The attributes that are common to motors and gaskets go in columns in the Part table.  The other attributes go in the Motor table or the Gasket table as appropriate.

The Motor_Gasket table has two columns:  MotorId and GasketID.  These are FKs that reference the appropriate table.  The PK for this table is the entire row.

Now the Motor_Gasket table implements the Contains relationship.  The "inheritance" of values between PartID and either MotorID or GasketID implement the "IS-A" relationship.

The other design is a two table design.

There are two tables:  Part, and Motor_Gasket.

Every motor and every gasket will occupy a row in the part table.  There will be a column called PartType that specifies what type of part it is.  All the attributes that describe motors or Gaskets are in the Part table.  Spaces that are inapplicable are set to NULL.

The Motor_Gasket table has two columns exactly as before, except both columns reference (different rows) of the Part table.

Which of these two designs is better?  It depends on the case at hand.

Comment: Makes sense! Things is, I was hoping for some more elaboration on the Has-a relationship between the specialized 'Engine' and 'Gasket' parts. Is that a valid diagram? Other than explicitly dividing those two parts into two types (which I'll agree is an important distinction), would there be much difference in the generated tables?
My gut says that there would only be a one-column change (the addition of a 'type' enumerated column), but maybe that's wrong ...

Comment: It depends. If you are doing single table inheritance, you just have one table for parts. and you have columns that pertain to all parts, columns that pertain to only engines, and columns that pertain only to gaskets. And also a type column. You'll end up with a lot of NULLS that in this case mean "not applicable". Those NULLS may or may not be a problem. The class table inheritance is more complicated. Visit the tag wiki.